# what does\?{argument} and ?{argument} mean in robotframework?

Tags: robotframework

What does `\?${TXN}=${status}` mean?
 I know `${status}` is an argument, but not quite sure what is `\?` ?

`?bId=${B_FK_AS}`  I am also not quite sure why there is a `?` before `bId` ?

I am new to robot framework, anyone can explain a bit?

Comment: can you give a bit more context? Is this used inside a keyword? How is it used? Also, your title mentions `\?{argument}` but the body of the question mentions `\?${TXN]`. Is the `$` part of what you're asking about?

Comment: `\?` and `?` are what I am asking for  @BryanOakley

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `\?` isn't special to robot framework. The backslash seems completely useless in this case. It's an escape character, but a question mark doesn't normally need to be escaped.

The question mark is also not special to robot. It's just a character like any other normal character, unless used in a context that interprets it differently such as using it in a regular expression.

In other words, `\?${TXN}=${status}` results in exactly the same string as `?${TXN}=${status}`. In both cases you end up with the backslash being removed, and the variables being replaced.

For example, this test case passes:

```
*** Variables ***
${TXN}     txn_value
${status}  status_value

*** Test cases ***
Example
    should be equal  \?${TXN}=${status}  ?${TXN}=${status}
    should be equal  \?${TXN}=${status}  ?txn_value=status_value
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  Why putting `?` before the variable? What does that mean?

Comment: @SumeiXu: Like my answer said, it doesn't mean anything. It's just a character. I don't know why someone put it there. Have you asked them?

Comment: It is escaped character